# Creating an array with $x elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How would I create an array in PHP that has `$x` empty elements? The `$x` is unknown and varying value. For example, if I wanted to create an array of 3 elements, I could just do:

```
$array = array(null,null,null);
```

However, I don't know what `$x` is and there could be million elements, I need to do this automatically.

Comment: BTW, do you realise that accessing a non-existent array element will return a `null`?  ie:
`$a = array("two", "vals"); $val = $a[5]; is_null($val); /* true */`

Comment: (though it will also cause a warning if you have `E_NOTICE` level warnings on)

Comment: @therefromhere Thats why the `array_key_exists` function exists.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As usual with PHP there's a function for this:

- [`array_fill()` - Fill an array with values](http://php.net/array_fill)

**Example:**

```
$array = array_fill(0, $x, 'value');
```

This will create an array filled with the $x elements valued 'value' starting at array offset 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
array_fill(0, $x, 'value')
```