# How to declare a 100x100 matrix in PHP

Tags: php

How can I declare a matrix having 100 rows and 100 columns in PHP?

Here is what I already know:

I know how to do it for 3x3:

```
$matrix=array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9)  
);
```

Or:

```
$matrix=[
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];
```

And then I have found a way of adding elements to a one dimensional array:

```
$t7=array("white","blue");
array_push($t7,"green","orange");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than trying to create a 100x100, I would suggest to check for the use and see if it's really the right way. So maybe the first question must be "what is the goal?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an array with $x elements in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935743/creating-an-array-with-x-elements-in-php)

Comment: You do it the same for 100x100 as it is for 3x3. `$m = [ [ xa0, ..., xa99 ], [ xb0, ..., xb99 ], ...... ]`. PHP is pretty convenient in this regard. You can also do ` $m = [] ; $m[0] = [] ; $m[0][0] = 123 ; $m[0][1] = 124; ... ; $m[1] = []; ..... $m[99][99] = 1234567;`

Comment: Yep, same as for 3x3. That's the answer, but it's probably useless to you, because it's not a good question. This is also known as "XY problem".

Comment: Unless you have something you want to fill the matrix _with_, you have already answered your own question - you write out the values you want to be in there. I'm sure your _actual_ requirement is to fill it with zeroes, or some particular pattern, but as written, it's like saying "How do I add 1 and 99? I know that to add 1 and 3 I write `1 + 3`".

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a couple of for loops, this is done only to a 5 x 5 matrix but just change the height and width to make it any size you like

```
$width = 5;
$height = 5;
$x = 1;

$matrix = [];

for( $i=0; $i < $width; $i++) {
    for( $j=0; $j < $height; $j++) {
        $matrix[$i][] = $x++;
    }
}

print_r($matrix);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 1,  [1] => 2,  [2] => 3,  [3] => 4,  [4] => 5 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 6,  [1] => 7,  [2] => 8,  [3] => 9,  [4] => 10 )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 11, [1] => 12, [2] => 13, [3] => 14, [4] => 15 )
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 16, [1] => 17, [2] => 18, [3] => 19, [4] => 20 )
    [4] => Array ( [0] => 21, [1] => 22, [2] => 23, [3] => 24, [4] => 25 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, there are several options. I decided to use the approach with two For loops. With the limiter (`$limit`) you set the matrix depth.

```
<?php
$matrix = [];
$limit = 3;
$counter = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++){
  $arr = [];
  for($j = 0; $j < $limit; $j++) {
    $arr[] = $counter++;
  }
  $matrix[$i] = $arr;  
}

print_r($matrix);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Code only answer is never a good thing...

Comment: @bZezzz You are right! I updated my answear and roughly describe my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are already two For loops in answers :-), I thought of using a while and the PHP Range function. But the For loop solution would also be my first choice.

```
$y = 0;
$matrix = [];
$range = 3;

while($y < $range) {
  $matrix[$y] = range($start = $start ?? 1, $start + ($range - 1));
  $start += $range;
  $y++;
}
print_r($matrix);

// ----
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you trying to define a 'square' matrix, we can use that to create a simple loop using `range` to get the required numbers:

```
<?php

$x = 5; // 100
$m = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    $m[] = range($i * $x, $i * $x + $x - 1);
}

var_dump($m);
```

Here we create an empty array, loop `n` times, add a new array to the original one starting at the previous value, until `+ 1 $y`

This will generate:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
    [3]=>
    int(3)
    [4]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(6)
    [2]=>
    int(7)
    [3]=>
    int(8)
    [4]=>
    int(9)
  }
... and some more
```

As you can test in [this online demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6VCwVbB1JpLJRdIR8dac3Gl5RcpaKhkArkG1gpA2kZBpQLE0NbWVKjmUgACldzoWKB0UWJeeipIpRZQhY4ClKGgDSJ0FQw1rblqubjKEoviU0pzCzRUcjWt//8HAA)